# How to solve error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'?

Tags: c++

This is my class and I get a very strange error.

```
#ifndef MYEXCEPTION_H
#define MYEXCEPTION_H

#include <string>
#include <exception>

//Error in next line
using namespace std;

class MyException : public exception {
public:
    MyException(string& whatsup) : message(whatsup) {  }
    ~MyException() throw() {}
    const char* what(){return message.c_str();}
private:
    string message;
};

#endif
```

Erro:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/myrecordproject
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -I/usr/local/include/cppunit -I/usr/local/include/boost -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
In file included from MyRecord.h:11,
                 from main.cpp:13:
MyException.h:14: error: expected unqualified-id before 'using'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `using namespace std` in a header file is looked down upon (and for good reason) and this isn't your actual code, it compiles just fine in: http://ideone.com/Xd8vPq

Comment: The error may be generated by a `#include` file in the source file that has `#include "MyException.h".  BTW, how are you differentiating between C language header files and C++ header files?